# error 1215: database design with foreign key

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am trying to create three tables such as associate, manager and attendance. The attendance table should be having employee and manager details from the other two table which should enable marking the attendance. I created this SQL script. I'm not sure where I am making mistake.

```
CREATE TABLE associate (
    id      INT             NOT NULL,
    idmanager INT           NOT NULL,
    emp_id  DATE  NOT NULL,
    emp_name VARCHAR(25)  NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (id)  REFERENCES attendance (associate_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (idmanager)  REFERENCES attendance (manager_idmanager)    ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)                  
)   ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE manager (
   id       INT     NOT NULL,
   mgr_usr_id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
   mgr_name VARCHAR(25) NOT null,
   KEY         (id),
   KEY         (mgr_usr_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (id)  REFERENCES associate (idmanager)   ON DELETE CASCADE,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
)  ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE attendance (
   sno      INT     NOT NULL,
   manager_idmanager INT    NOT NULL,
   associate_id INT     NOT NULL,
   date_stamp DATETIME,
   state BIT    NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (sno)
)  ENGINE=INNODB;
```

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue of ordering.  For example, the first statement executed is

```
CREATE TABLE associate (
```

which references `attendance`.  However, the `attendance` table has not yet been created.  Switch the order so that any tables that reference other tables come last.

Alternatively, don't put the FOREIGN KEY constraints in the CREATE statements, but them at the end of your script with ALTER TABLE statements.  Consider:

```
CREATE TABLE associate (
  id        INT          NOT NULL,
  idmanager INT          NOT NULL,
  emp_id    DATE         NOT NULL,
  emp_name  VARCHAR(25)  NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE attendance (
  sno               INT       NOT NULL,
  manager_idmanager INT       NOT NULL,
  associate_id      INT       NOT NULL,
  date_stamp        DATETIME,
  state             BIT       NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (sno)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

ALTER TABLE associate ADD FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES associate(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

## Edit

The above is just syntax.  To model the requested problem consider *orthogonality* of information.  You might also see/hear "normalization."  The basic concept is this: have only one copy of your information.  The schema should have a **single** point of authority for all data.  For example, if a user has a birthdate, make sure you don't have an ancillary column that also stores their birthday; it's superfluous information and can lead to data errors.

In this case, what is the relationship?  What must come first for the other to exist?  Can an attendance be had without a manager?  How about a manager without attendance?  The former makes no sense.  In this case then, I would actually use a third table, to form a hierarchy.

Then, consider that maybe roles change in a company.  It would not behoove the DB architect to hard code roles as tables.  Consider:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  id      INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name    VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE role (
  id    INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY( id ),
  UNIQUE( name )
) ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO role (name, description) VALUES
  ('associate', 'An associate is a ...'),
  ('manager', 'A manager follows ...');


CREATE TABLE employee_role (
  employee_id  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  role_id      INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (employee_id, role_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (idemployee_id)  REFERENCES employee_id (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (role_id)  REFERENCES role (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;


CREATE TABLE attendance (
   sno               INTEGER NOT NULL,
   employee_id       INTEGER NOT NULL,
   date_stamp        DATETIME,
   state             BIT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (sno),
   FOREIGN KEY (idemployee_id)  REFERENCES employee_id (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)  ENGINE=INNODB;
```

From this schema, the attendance needs only one foreign key because *everyone* is an employee.  Employee's can have multiple roles, and they can change.  Further, role definitions can change without needing to resort to costly DDL statements (data definition layer changes, like ALTER TABLE), and can be modified with simple DML (data manipulation layer changes, like UPDATE TABLE).  The former involves rewriting all entries in the tables, and changing schemas, while the latter involves changing individual entries.

Comment: It looks like there's more in error than ordering. The relationships are backward, where `manager.id` should not be both PK and FK.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski good point.  I read the question too fast.  I'll address that in an edit.

Comment: Thanks @hunteke! Great help. Working on it. Will share the result in sometime! And thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @hunteke, if i want to insert values in the employee table, and i also wanted to have the data added in employee_role table, do i have to consider writing stored procedure or just a simple query, if so how the above relation works even for the attendance table?

Comment: @EJSingh they are independent tables, and that's the entire point of _normalization_.  You insert data into `employee` irrespective of what's in `role` and vice versa.  The sole link is the `employee_role` table, which maintains the relationship with ACID compliance as per the FOREIGN KEY constraints in the schema.  Mp stored procedure necessary.